# CSS: How to horizontally center div with overflow:auto that contains float-left elements

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have a div with overflow-auto that contains float-left elements as you can see in the code below (I'm using the latest bootstrap to style my page). My problem is how do I horizontally center the div?

Code:

```
<div class="overflow-auto">
    <div class="card float-left mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
    <div class="card float-left mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
    <div class="card float-left mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
    <div class="card float-left mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
    <div class="card float-left mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Designing a page with floating elements is rather a nasty business, I would suggest you take a look at the the [bootstrap flex documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/). Seems maybe hard at first, but once you understand the concept, it's much easier to design your elements both horizontally and vertically!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that it would be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Jacob, use bootstrap flex is much easier and I was able to achieve what I wanted in the code below.

Solution:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
    <div class="card mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
    <div class="card mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
    <div class="card mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
    <div class="card mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
    <div class="card mx-2 my-4 shadow" style="width: 250px;">...</div>
</div>
```